# Unicorn not reloading with USR2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unicorn

I'm trying to reload unicorn with a USR2 signal, but I get the following error on the logs:

```
E, [2012-04-13T21:27:00.801192 #24474] ERROR -- : old PID:23820 running with existing pid=/home/user/app.git/tmp/unicorn.pid.oldbin, refusing rexec
```

I've search the internets but don't have a clue. It seems that unicorn is trying to write to the pid file? I'm issuing a `kill -s USR2 PID`

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into this today. I'm assuming you have previously sent USR2 to unicorn, and this is now the second time you're trying to do so.

Per the [unicorn documentation on signals](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/SIGNALS.html) and USR2: "A separate QUIT should be sent to the original process once the child is verified to be up and running."

In this particular case, you'd pass the old PID to kill

```
kill -s QUIT 23820
```

Or, you can take advantage of the fact this old PID is stored a known file (referenced in your error message) alongside the "current" PID, and execute:

```
kill -s QUIT `cat /home/user/app.git/tmp/unicorn.pid.oldbin`
```